# ExoPlayer 2 life cycle inside PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a ViewPager with different number of pages that is held by a RecyclerView which is under a Fragment. My ViewPager only use PagerAdapter since it is not too expensive unlike FragmentPagerAdapter. Now I want to play a certain video if and only this view becomes visible to a user or in ViewPager, once the user swipe to the next page I want the previous video play to stop same thing with swiping back. I want to play only what is visible to a user and in a ViewPager itself.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue that exoplayer fragment does not load in the other pages. Were you able to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it a huge process with a large implementation of interface. I also use libraries like EventBus